# Can php5-fpm be configured for separate php executables?

Tags: php, php-fpm, executable

Can php5-fpm be configured to use php executables?

I want to compile php separately for some websites on the same server where as some of them use the same executable. Can php5-fpm be configured that way?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to compile it differently. Surely just using a different `php.ini` for each fpm pool that loads different extensions would be sufficient.

Comment: I prefer to be able to move projects from one server to another with minimum changes required on the server. It isn't always possible or convenient for central server resources to be customized for your needs